# Is it possible to get an array as a cell in cucumber parameters table?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

What is the currect way to write it?

```
Scenario: Data tables
  Given I have the following order
    | vegetable |    array         | cost |
    | cucumber  |   1,2,3,4        |  10  |
    | carrot    |   empty array    |   6  |
    | potato    |   1,2,3          |   4  |

public class OrderItem {

    private String vegetable;
    private int[] array;
    private int cost;
}

@Given("^I have another order$")
public void i_have_another_order(List<OrderItem> list) throws Throwable {
    for (OrderItem orderItem : list) {
        // do something with my OrderItem..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working fine. I have checked it. The code is

```
public class OrderItem {

private String vegetable;
private int[] array;
private int cost;

public void set(String veg,int[] arr,int cos){
    this.vegetable=veg;
    this.array=arr;
    this.cost=cos;
}

public String getVeg(){
    return this.vegetable;
}
```

}

```
@Given("^I have the following order$")
public void i_have_another_order(List<OrderItem> list) throws Throwable {
    for (OrderItem orderItem : list) {
        // do something with my OrderItem..
        System.out.println(orderItem.getVeg());
    }
}
```